# Loop through array with subloop to create subsections in PHP

Tags: php, loops

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Type Description
color red
color blue
color yellow
shape circle
shape square
animal dog
animal cat
animal bird
animal cow
```

In PHP, I need to loop through it and render it like this:

```
Color
  red
  blue
  yellow


Shape
  circle
  square


Animal
  dog
  cat
  bird
  cow
```

I believe I need to use a a While loop and then have subloop inside of that while loop somehow.
What is that most straightforward way to render the data this way?

Comment: Loop through and echo, check that the `type` matches previous `type`, if it didnt output `type` in heading offest.

Comment: What data format exactly is that table? Database table? Or text input?

Comment: The data is in an array at this point. As simple as the example given.

Comment: Post your current code. Should be able to use a `foreach` and a conditional check for the `type`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table is in a file named input.txt that's located in the same folder where you php script is located:

```
$fp = fopen('input.txt', 'r') or die('I cannot find your file');
while(false !== ($line = fgets($fp))) {
    $chunks = explode(" ", trim($line));

    if (count($chunks) < 2) {
       continue;
    }
    $chunks = array_values(array_filter($chunks));
    $output[ucfirst($chunks[0])][] = $chunks[1];
}
unset($output['Type']);


foreach ($output as $type=>$elements) {
    echo $type . PHP_EOL;
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
        echo "\t" . $element . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```